# JasperReport Exception: FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions: Loading font extensions from fonts.xml

Tags: java, linux, fonts, jasper-reports

I just finished a project, but when i put it in the production environment the JasperReport presents error on font.xml. I try run the project on my machine on terminal (linux) and the same error apears, work only if i run on Netebeans. For why work on Netbeans and on terminal no?

My project is simple, i generate on PDF and send it by e-mail. The structure is:

[image]

jasperreports_extension.properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.arial=fonts.xml
```

fonts.xml:

```
<fontFamily name="Arial">
    <normal>fonts/Arial.ttf</normal>
    <bold>fonts/Arial Bold.ttf</bold>
    <italic>fonts/Arial Italic.ttf</italic>
    <boldItalic>fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf</boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    <exportFonts>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>
```

POM:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>    
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>    
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<build>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.maven-taglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-taglib-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>taglibdocjar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0-beta-2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.maven-taglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-taglib-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
                <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>5.5.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.20100224</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error:

```
19/11/18 00:00:00 DEBUG BaseReportFiller.<init>:149 - Fill 1: created for boleto-default
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG BaseReportFiller.<init>:177 - created delayed actions 1 for filler 1
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG ExtensionsEnvironment.createDefaultRegistry:87 - Instantiating extensions registry class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries:150 - Loading registries for cache key sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG JRLoader.collectResources:791 - Found resource jasperreports_extension.properties at jar:file:/home/matheus/Downloads/myProject-1.0.0.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries:182 - Loading JasperReports extension properties resource jar:file:/home/matheus/Downloads/myProject-1.0.0.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries:264 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry:289 - Instantiating extensions registry for fonts using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
19/11/18 00:00:01 DEBUG FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions:88 - Loading font extensions from fonts.xml
Exception in thread "TestThread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:111)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:234)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:134)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:648)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:970)
    at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.geraRelatorio(GeradorDeBoleto.java:119)
    at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.geraPDF(GeradorDeBoleto.java:160)
    at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.geraPDF(GeradorDeBoleto.java:210)
    at br.com.caelum.stella.boleto.transformer.GeradorDeBoleto.geraPDFStream(GeradorDeBoleto.java:229)
    at br.com.company.test.TestThread.run(TestThread.java:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You have some more stacktrace for it?, is there another "Caused by"?

Comment: No. Only this show to me

Comment: Maybe problem with font.xml but I would not be 100÷ sure its actually the xml, that type error you get can get from problem loading a font (in stream) problem parsing jrxml (xerces hell) we would need some more info about the actual error

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of @Petter Friberg i was able to identify the real origin of my error, who was in the Jasper Report properties file.

Below is the link that helped me solve my problem:

[Jasperreports engine JRRuntimeException on report().show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440172/jasperreports-engine-jrruntimeexception-on-report-show)